# ng-click according to element ID

Tags: html, angularjs

So I have a `ng-repeat` iterating through an array that contains the elements form an API. Through the `ng-repeat` , I print out the same number of div(s) containing the names of some properties as the number of property present in the API in different objects. Now the next step that I want is that when I click on any property Name div, another screen is opened up which has the details of the property ( details are then fetched from the API which I can do). What I am not able to do is how to use the `ng-click` that it goes to the details screen but according the property that is clicked. I know that somehow I need to pass the property ID in `ng-click` and lead it to a different screen. Can't figure out how. Kinda am new to `Angularjs` so can someone help?

```html
<div ng-repeat="prop in propertyDetails" class="propertyCard"
     ng-click="Something here which I cant figure out ">
    <p class="propSummaryName">{{ prop.name }}</p>
<div>
```

Now when the divs are created for the different properties when I click on one of them a new screen comes and then I show there what I want to show for the property.

PS- for property ID : prop.id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use can directly write function call.

```
<div ng-repeat="prop in propertyDetails" class="propertyCard"
 ng-click="propDetails(prop.id)">
<p class="propSummaryName">{{ prop.name }}</p>
```

```
$scope.showDetails(propId) {
// do want ever you want to };
```

- If you want to show property details on another screen then you can use
  modal or routing.

Comment: I did. In the on click function I used $location.path('/my.html'), but it didnt work.

Comment: You navigate by virtual name not by html name. Have you added routing in your project ?

Comment: Yes i have added routing

Comment: Then you might have added something like this:
when('/my', {
          template: 'my.html',
          controller: 'myController',
        });
Then use the $location.path('/my') to naigate.

Comment: yes. Not exactly that but I know how to add the routing. Also, If I straight away type ng-click="go('/my.html')" then is works. but i need to redirect it according the clicekd item

Comment: $location.path is part of angularjs API so better to use angularjs routing approach.

Comment: Oh. Okay. I look into that

Comment: So what I did now is I made a function for ng-click like this:  ng-click="getPropertyDetails(prop)", in my controller js I wrote $scope.getPropertyDetails = $location.path('/new');   function(prop){  console.log(prop.id) }; this is working just fine. It goes to a new screen and I can see id logged in the console and it was changing with the change in property that I click. Now I wanted to print to the id in the new screen so in that html i wrote <p>{{ propID }}</p> with $scope.propID = prop.id; in my controller js click function. But nothing happened. How do I print data on the new screen now

Comment: You will have to pass data in url as params. Please check the exact syntax.
and then get the data in rendered controller.

Answer (score 1):

hey it's Simple You can call the @scope function in the ng Click and inside the function call the reset service and then open the popup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="test">
<div ng-init="loadData()">
<div ng-repeat="prop in propertyDetails" class="propertyCard"
     ng-click="openMyPopUp(prop)">
    <p class="propSummaryName">{{ prop.name }}</p>
<div>



<div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          Name : {{popupData.name}}
           Id : {{popupData.id}}
        </div>

        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('test', function($scope, $http) {

    var popup = angular.element("#myModal");
//for hide model
popup.modal('hide');

  var url = 'your-url.com/rest/api'
    $scope.loadData = function(){
        $http.get(url).then(function(res){
            $scope.propertyDetails = res.data;
        });
    }

    $scope.openMyPopUp= function(data) {
        $http.get(url + '?id=' + data.id).then(function(res){
            $scope.popupData = res.data;
        });
        //for show model
        popup.modal('show');
    }


});
</script>
```

If you need to rederct to another page mean you can do like this

```
 var url = "http://" + $window.location.host + "/Account/Login";
        $log.log(url);
        $window.location.href = url;
```

inside this function

Comment: Please help me understand this,  so basically you are getting a popup when clicked and displaying the property Name there, yes?

Comment: no no. But I want that instead of the popup a new screen comes up on click where I can show the data. not a popup. can it be done?

Comment: This code opens up a popup on the same screen, right? But I want to redirect to a new separate screen,

Comment: `window.location = "http://www.my-domain.com/login?id=" + prop.id ` i hope this will work

Comment: But I have lots of data to show. It is basically the user can see the properties that he has and then to see the full details of the property(which has way too much data) a new screen appears.

Comment: Ok k bro @RohanVaish did you got the answer

Comment: So I tried your thing with the popup. Works nice. Can't figure out to a new screen. :'/